# How to load module based on a configuration file in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several defined modules. I don't want to load them all into my App. Instead, I want to load them based on a configuration file. For example

Module1:

```
angular.module('section1', [])
```

Module2:

```
angular.module('section2', [])
```

In each of the module, it will have its own HTML template and business logic. Then in the app.module.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['module1', 'module2']);
```

module1 and module2 will both be loaded together. I don't want to hard code it, instead, I will have a configuration file, something like:

```
[{'module1': true}, {'module2':false}]
```

Eventually, every time when the app is launched, I read the configuration file and then decide which modules will be loaded and which modules will not. In above example, module1 will be loaded while module 2 will not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can `manually bootstrap` angular js application. It will help you in adding conditions and deciding which module to load

Here is how you do manual bootstrapping in angular.

```
angular.element(function() {
  if(/* condition */ {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['module1']);
  } else {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['module2']);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you done this in practice? I am extremely interested in loading only modules that apply to roles that a user profile has access to. Is there anything more to this from an Angular perspective? (of course I can fill in the details in terms of how I would go about generating the array of modules based upon profile). Is there a small sample you could provide? Would be very grateful!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap - you can check this out for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out the source on ng-app and debugged thru it and it is pretty basic for my use case. Really just comes down to these 2 lines which is similar to yours (config ends up being { strictDi: true})

 config.strictDi = getNgAttribute(appElement, 'strict-di') !== null;
 bootstrap(appElement, module ? [module] : [], config);

Comment: There's really no need to bother with bootstrapping Angular manually in this case, if your configuration is loaded along with Angular.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen : The statement you made is not correct. Although for majority of application, you wouldn't need to bother with bootstrapping Angular manually, but there may be cases where you may need manual bootstrapping. Suppose, you want your angular application to launch only when a particular condition is met or after some other activity has taken place. Manual Bootstrapping gives you more control, so I suggest definitely check it out. Don't discourage someone to not learn a new way just because you don't think it's efficient.

Comment: I've done manual bootstrapping, I've even written a custom bootstrapping module, to postpone bootstrapping until requirejs had loaded all resources. There are certainly use cases for manual bootstrapping. I'm just arguing that this isn't one of them (hence why I wrote *in this case* above). I'm not discouraging him to not learn it, I'm just trying to answer his question correctly, with as little complexity as possible, and with his question in mind, there's absolutely no need to bootstrap angular manually. There's no point in making things harder than necessary to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the module dependency array before you define your angular module and pass the array in as a variable. If you have complete control over the configuration files and how they're loaded, the config file could simply be the array of dependencies. Like so:

```
var config = ['module1', 'module2'];
angular.module('app', config);
```

This is assuming you have multiple config files and then load the one you want for that particular context.

If you want to have all module dependency configurations in a single file, you could format it like this:

```
var config = {
    'profileA': [ 'module1' ],
    'profileB': [ 'module2' ]
};
var currentProfile = 'profileA';
angular.module('app', config[currentProfile]);
```

Since it's configured before the Angular application is defined (and thus bootstrapped), Angular wouldn't care where your module dependencies come from. As long as the actual modules' .js files have been loaded. You wouldn't be able to change profile without a browser refresh though.